# TextField takes unicode in Django

Tags: django, unicode, django-models

I am trying to save a string contains characters whose ordinal is not in range(128) into database. The field is declared as TextField in model and when I called the save() method, an exception was thrown:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 434, in save self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 500, in save_base rows = manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val)._update(values)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 491, in _update return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 861, in execute_sql cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 717, in execute_sql sql, params = self.as_sql()
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 826, in as_sql val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 28, in inner return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 28, in inner return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 276, in get_db_prep_save return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 53, in inner return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 652, in get_db_prep_value value = self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 647, in get_prep_value return self.to_python(value)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 610, in to_python if not ansi_date_re.search(value):
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Here is what I did:

```
str_unicode = str.encode('utf-8')
m = MyModel.new(str = str_unicode)
m.save()
```

So what should I do to enable the unicode compatibility?

**Updated**: I am currently using sqlite3 for development, python 2.6.1 and Django 1.2.4 on Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is I didn't load mysql settings in django's database configuration, which is not related to unicode problem I presented.

The configuration should be like this:

```
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
           'NAME': 'db',
           'USER': 'xxx',
           'PASSWORD': 'xxx', 
           'HOST': 'localhost',
           'PORT': '3306', 
           'OPTIONS' : {
              "init_command": "SET storage_engine=INNODB",
              'read_default_file': '/etc/my.cnf',
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

utf-8 is *not* unicode! This line:

```
str_unicode = str.encode('utf-8')
```

does the *opposite* of what you intended. It takes unicode, and converts it to utf-8. Don't do this.

Comment: 100% agreed, however from reading the traceback it turns out his problem has nothing to do with the TextField at all. lol...

Comment: Hmmmm that might be confusing for readers.
UTF-8 is a variable-width character encoding used for electronic communication. Defined by the Unicode Standard, the name is derived from Unicode Transformation Format – 8-bit. UTF-8 is capable of encoding all 1,112,064 valid character code points in Unicode using one to four one-byte code units

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not with the TextField at all. If you look at the code referenced in the traceback, you're triggering an exception from within `DateField`'s `to_python` method. You can [see the relevant code here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L610). Basically it looks like you're passing something inappropriate as the input to another field on your model.

Lesson to be learned: ALWAYS READ THE TRACEBACK CAREFULLY!

As a side note, if you really want to coerce something to unicode in Python call the builtin `unicode` type:

```
str_unicode = unicode(str)
```

Using the `encode` method to convert to UTF-8 does something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Django works fine with unicode.

But if your input are not properly converted you will have trouble.
As an exemple : I have had a lot of trouble with an old MyISAM database populated wrongly by a bugged php script.
Check your input.

What database backend do you use? What level of python ?

Comment: I am currently using sqlite3 for development and python 2.6.1 on Mac.